# Computer Forensic Timeline Tool for live system

Tags: windows, log-analysis, disk-analysis, forensics, windows-registry

I am troubleshooting PCs and many times I'd like to find out what a user did before the PC or programs of the PC stopped working. The tool should at least collect information from:

- Add/remove programs information
- Windows Updates
- MRU lists in Registry
- System event log
- File modification dates on disk (today I use [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/))
- deleted files (recycle bin and really deleted) (today I use [FTK Imager Lite](http://www.accessdata.com/support/product-downloads))
- Connected hardware (also removed ones) (today I use [NirSoft USBDeView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html))

I know there are programs which are used in Computer Forensics, but usually they take a complete disk and/or memory image and then analyze it on another PC. I don't need this feature, because

- I am allowed to make changes to the target PC
- It takes too much time
- I don't have so much disk space for doing the analysis
- I don't need to analyze (most) file contents later
- I am not trying to bring someone to court

I also don't need to analyze things which (usually) have no impact on the behavior of the PC, like

- chat logs
- email
- browser history

Besides collecting the information, the tool should be able to:

- run on the target PC directly, but without installation
- sort all data by time
- filter the data by time (define a date range)
- filter the data by event type

If it cannot filter, then it should be able to export to a common file format like CSV or Excel so that I can do the filtering there.

OS: Windows XP to Windows 8.1.

File system: NTFS

License: commercial use needed

Price: gratis and OpenSource preferred. Otherwise up to 100 € one-time price. No monthly payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed that there's no such tool out there, so I wrote my own: [Live System Timeline Builder](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/live-system-timeline-builder-download/). It combines many NirSoft utilities and exports into Excel format.